# Can't load audio files with librosa

Tags: python, ffmpeg, librosa

Unless I use one of `librosa`'s native 'example' audio files which are in some format '.ogg', I cannot load audio.

Every github issue and SO answer says I need to install ffmpeg. I found a python package called `ffmpeg` and installed it into my virtual environment. I also found some sort of multi-purpose program called `ffmpeg` and installed it onto my Windows machine, and added it's location to my PATH variable.

I still get the same warnings and errors that everyone else is getting:

```
c:\users\wesle\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py:162: UserWarning: PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.
  warnings.warn("PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.

   115     # All backends failed!
--> 116     raise NoBackendError()
```

I can find no resolution for this problem despite the number of people asking for help on it.

Comment: Is this the `ffmpeg` you downloaded?
https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
If not, provide the source please?

Comment: A full command line output would also be appreciated, if possible.
(ie. including the traceback)

Comment: @AnAnonymousUser No, I used the build from here: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, which was what was the recommended as the best location for a windows build on ffmpeg.org.

Comment: @AnAnonymousUser After installing ffmpeg and restarting my machine, `librosa` can no longer be found, making it difficult to re-create the error. If I get it to work again, I'll post the full trace. However, it is identical to 99% of the errors you will find by googling this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with this one.

But to anyone else working on this, a more complete output of this error is here: https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/219

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what fileformat you are trying to load, but in most cases installing ffmpeg is the solution to this problem. It is important to add the "../bin/" directory to *PATH* and restart the environment. Using the "set" command from prompt you can check that the current path contains the folder.